# How Can I dismiss a ViewController from a popup callback

Tags: appconkit

I am creating a popup message and show this popup over an action from a button.
Now I am trying to dismiss the SplitViewController, on that the popup is shown, from the popup callback.
But in my case it fails, so how is the right way to do this?

```
function showPopUp
{
        var popup = vMobileController.solutionController().createPopUp();
    popup.setMessage("Testmessage?");
    popup.setTitle("test");
    popup.addOption("yes",popupYES);
    popup.addOption("no",popupNO);
    popup.show();
}


function popupNO()
{
        var vSolutionController = vMobileController.solutionController();
var vDatamanager = vMobileController.dataManager();
var vLogger = vMobileController.logger();

var currViewC = vSolutionController.rootViewController().firstSubViewControllerByName("overview_split");
currViewC.dismissModal();

}


function popupYES()
{

}
```

Comment: Is this view presented modally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modal presented controller is never a sub controller of the root view controller. To access modal presented controllers use the accessing methods of the solution controller itself.

```
var vSolutionController = mobileController.solutionController();
var vControllertoDismiss = vSolutionController.findFirstViewController("overview_split");
if (vControllertoDismiss) {
    vControllertoDismiss.dismissModal();
} else {
    logger.debug("Coun't find controller overview_split");
}
```

If this also not find your controller you might misspelled the controllers name? Use `Screens.overview_split` to let the ACK autocomplete the screen name.

```
var vControllertoDismiss = vSolutionController.findFirstViewController(Screens.overview_split);
```